# Why is my formula not being evaluated in Excel VSTO Workbook using VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto

My Code is entering the formula in the cell correctly, but it is not evaluated unless I either double click the cell and hit Enter or go to the formula bar and hit enter. The formula is a dynamic formula using the VSTACK function. I have used this same formula in a VBA workbook without a problem.With VBA the formula is evaluated as soon as it is populated.

Partial code. The checkbox array is used for a different function, but the code runs in the same sub.

Dim i As Integer
Dim chkName As String
Dim chkState As String
Dim StackList As String = "Empty"
Dim chkTbl As String
Dim checkboxarray As String(,)

```
    i = Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox).Count
    ReDim checkboxarray(i, 1)
    i = 0
    For Each chk In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf chk Is CheckBox Then
            chkName = chk.Name
            chkState = chk.Checked
            If chkName IsNot "Clear" And chkName IsNot "QCopy" And chkName IsNot "Project" And chkName IsNot "OrderbyCat" Then

                checkboxarray(i, 0) = chkName
                checkboxarray(i, 1) = chkState.ToUpper
                i += 1

                If chkState = "True" Then
                    chkTbl = "Tbl" & chkName

                    If StackList = "Empty" Then

                        StackList = chkTbl
                    Else
                        StackList = StackList & ", " & chkTbl
                    End If

                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Dim DestinationRange As Excel.Range
    DestinationRange = Globals.wsAdmin.Range("NamePaste").Resize(i, 2)
    DestinationRange.Value = checkboxarray
    Dim Rng As Excel.Range = Globals.wsAdmin.Range("CombinedRngPaste")
    Rng.Formula = {"=VSTACK(" & StackList & ")"}
```

I have double checked the cell format is set to general and that the calculation mode is set to automattic. I am wrapping the formula in {} to keep excel from adding the @ to the formula which will break it. I also notice that I can not turn this feature off as I have in the past using (File-Options-Advanced-Untick Extend range formats). I tried using FormulaArray which I know is wrong, but it works except it populates #NA in every cell below the result range because the formula is in every cell.

Comment: Try `Rng.Formula2R1C1 = "=VSTACK(" & StackList & ")"`

Comment: Works link a charm! Thank you so much. I've struggled with this for some time